# How to reference a tag soap xml?

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

I'm working on an application that makes a query to a `SOAP` web service. The authentication tag as I make a reference, because when the key step says it was not informed of any key integration.

The integration of key is as follows,

```
soap.addProperty("ChaveIntegracao", this.chaveDeIntegracao);
```

What should I do to solve the problem of factor authentication? This is my `WSDL`.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:con="ConsultaClientes">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <con:ConsultaClientes soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <Autenticacao xsi:type="urn:Autenticacao" xmlns:urn="urn:RouterBoxConsultas">
            <ChaveIntegracao xsi:type="xsd:string"></ChaveIntegracao>
         </Autenticacao>
      </con:ConsultaClientes>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is my entire code.

```
private void consultaClientes() {
    SoapObject soap = new SoapObject("urn:RouterBoxConsultas", "ConsultaClientes");

    /* soap.addProperty("Autenticacao", "urn:RouterBoxConsultas");*/

    soap.addProperty("ChaveIntegracao",this.chaveDeIntegracao);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soap);

    Log.i("RouterBox", "Chamando WebService para consulta de Clientes");

    String url = "###########################################";


    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);

    try {

        httpTransport.call("ConsultaClientes", envelope);
        //Object msg = envelope.getResponse();

        SoapPrimitive msg = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

        Log.d("RouterBox", "Clientes: " + msg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to see more code. Are you creating the `Autenticacao` tag?

Comment: @KNeerajLal, 
I added the code the question, authentication tag already exists on the web service.

Comment: @KNeerajLal, Can you help me?

Comment: Is `Autenticacao` a custom class?

Comment: Autenticacao  means authentication.@KNeerajLal

Comment: Is it a custom class?

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but we are going to use RestFul. @KNeerajLal